# ajax POST request not working on apache url rewrite

Tags: ajax, apache, perl, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite url everything works fine but form post is not working.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /myapp/ http://localhost:8080/ keepalive=On
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/users/(.*) http://127.0.0.1/myapp/users/$1 
</VirtualHost>
```

Please Help me in resolving the issue.

Thanks,
Saravanan

Answer (score 0):

It is due to use of `http://` in the target URI of your rule which will do redirect instead of rewrite. Change that to:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?users/(.*) http://127.0.0.1/myapp/users/$1 [P,L,NC]
```

Comment: to redirect from 8080 to 80 port